# ArcGIS JS Modular Feature Layers? Possible?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

My ultimate goal is a map which can toggle the visibility of layers on an ArcGIS map. However the data I need to use is not available as a feature service, I have to build it programatically from feature collections. I want to make AMD modules that will return FeatureLayers to a script that is in control of the map. I also want the FeatureLayers to contain events.

Does anyone have any advice on how to accomplish this? Can I setup the events and map markers without access to the map object? Maybe pass the map object to the FeatureLayer constructor? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is what the code that calls my modules looks like.

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/request", "dojox/layout/TableContainer", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer", "esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
             "esri/dijit/Popup", "esri/tasks/query", "dgrid/Grid", "dojo/json", "js/cbibsModule", "dojo/domReady!"],

              function (parser, array, request, TableContainer, BorderContainer, ContentPane, AccordionContainer, map, FeatureLayer, Popup, query, Grid, JSON, cbibsModule) {
                function init(){
                    _map = new map("mapDiv", {
                      basemap: "oceans",
                      center: [-77.0357, 38.7877],
                      zoom: 7
                    });
                    var cbibs = new cbibsModule();
                    var fl = cbibs.requestCBIBS(_map);
                    console.log(_map);
                }
                dojo.ready(init);
              }
            )
```

`cbibs.requestCBIBS(_map)` should not only return a Feature Layer object, but should also pass the `_map` variable by reference so the Feature Layer can attach events to it. This is not working. I don't get any errors but the map does not display.

**UPDATE: This is my updated code but my markers are still not drawing on the map, nor am I getting any errors. I build the Graphic objects in a module and return them in an array. I then add them to the Graphics Layer and add it to the Map (at least I think that's what's going on). Any suggestions??**

```
          function (parser, ready, array, request, TableContainer, BorderContainer, ContentPane, AccordionContainer, map, GraphicsLayer, Popup, query, Grid, JSON, cbibsGfxModule, crwoModule) {
            var Map, gfxLayer;
            function init(){
                Map = new map("mapDiv", {
                  basemap: "oceans",
                  center: [-77.0357, 38.7877],
                  zoom: 7
                }),
                dojo.connect(Map, "onLoad", addGraphics);
            };

            function addGraphics(){
                gfxLayer = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();
                var gfxContainer = []; // Store array returned by cbibsGfxModule.getAllCurrentReadings()
                var cbibs = new cbibsGfxModule();
                gfxContainer = cbibs.getAllCurrentReadings();
                array.forEach (gfxContainer, function (item, i) {
                   gfxLayer.graphics.push(item); 
                });                    
                Map.addLayer(gfxLayer);
                console.log(Map);
            };
          dojo.ready(init);
          }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something,  But why aren't you using a graphics layer?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm still new to this. Could you please tell me why I should be using a graphics layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have understood, you want two things:

- You want all your features in one layer which you can switch on and off
- This Layer needs to have certain Events.

What you are looking for, is called a [Graphics Layer](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/graphicslayer.html). It consists of Graphics, which are basically an array of Features.

You should look at this Document: [Working with graphics](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/inside_graphics.html)

You should instantiate a new Graphics Layer, add your features to it, and then add the graphics layer to the map.